# Converting a CryptoStream to using declaration makes memory stream empty when text less than 15 chars

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, memorystream, cryptostream

I am having a strange issue when encrypting a text with C#.
ReSharper (and I agree) recommends to replace the `using` block on this code:

```
public object GetEncryptedOrDefault(object value, ICryptoTransform encryptor)
{
    if (encryptor is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encryptor));
    }
    var isEncryptionNeeded = value != null;
    if (isEncryptionNeeded)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            var valueAsText = value.ToString();
            writer.Write(valueAsText);
        }

        var encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    return default;
}
```

to this simplified one (notice the using declaration instead of the block):

```
public object GetEncryptedOrDefault(object value, ICryptoTransform encryptor)
{
    if (encryptor is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encryptor));
    }
    var isEncryptionNeeded = value != null;
    if (isEncryptionNeeded)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        var valueAsText = value.ToString();
        writer.Write(valueAsText);

        var encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    return default;
}
```

Well.. the first one works good and it's able to encrypt the text.
However the second one does not work! the `encryptedData` is empty and therefore it produces an empty `encryptedText`.

I can't see the problem. Why?

---

**UPDATE 1**
Thanks to Emanuel's answer I was able to make it work ONLY when text to encrypt was larger than 15 characters. **This is really odd**. Under 15 characters, only the code with the "old fashioned" using block would work as opposed to the one that uses the using declaration.

I reproduced the problem [in this sample repo at Github](https://github.com/sunnyatticsoftware/issue-encryption-stream-empty/tree/32b14b7b142afd6352a0ecd986090bd9a8cd62a1).

Even if this problem is related to the AesManaged (which I don't know), **why would the first method succeed and the second fail** for any text with 15 or less characters?

This is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var encryptor = GetEncryptor();
        var text = "Under 15 characters this text causes problems";
        while (text.Length >= 0)
        {
            text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result Method A with {text.Length} characters: {GetWorkingEncrypted(text, encryptor)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Result Method B with {text.Length} characters: {GetNonWorkingEncrypted(text, encryptor)}");
        }
    }

    private static string GetWorkingEncrypted(string text, ICryptoTransform encryptor)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            writer.Write(text);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        var encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        if (encryptedData.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Encrypted data is 0 for text {text}");
        }
        var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    private static string GetNonWorkingEncrypted(string text, ICryptoTransform encryptor)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        writer.Write(text);
        writer.Flush();

        var encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        if (encryptedData.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Encrypted data is 0 for text \"{text}\" with length {text.Length}");
        }
        var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    private static ICryptoTransform GetEncryptor()
    {
        var aesManaged =
            new AesManaged
            {
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
            };

        return aesManaged.CreateEncryptor();
    }
}
```

And this the result of the execution:

```
Result Method A with 44 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3937Peo255iHRylA9DF0lf4K+
Result Method B with 44 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 43 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934Pwaqyce+T6SG3WaqnzNRt
Result Method B with 43 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 42 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3936tIT0560Lky1gz3FXKHU3Y
Result Method B with 42 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 41 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934xr6AiKuSxRet/e8iWhLEV
Result Method B with 41 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 40 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3937gCR2Lf9zQClOlCFw51dVo
Result Method B with 40 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 39 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3936OjZ4HEtzkcIjVMUJcDzum
Result Method B with 39 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 38 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3936ti1b7pskEFKb2zJrRkVaD
Result Method B with 38 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 37 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3937rKO73A+OiHd1aAMqOd3Df
Result Method B with 37 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 36 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934/BNp0BiYZPRMUUiODp/kb
Result Method B with 36 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 35 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3935sjuGp/uE4fVOn26J1ESzH
Result Method B with 35 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 34 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+39360AAj7hDLcnbMZH7aknpDl
Result Method B with 34 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 33 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3935EfO82m/jR81he3Jt4z1h+
Result Method B with 33 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 32 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934zeVj3CoE5YIFK8/g07QmH
Result Method B with 32 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJH/fCQbNFhCvzfbFP+3934=
Result Method A with 31 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZCRCNZXU9Ndp7uKLJkUXFsw=
Result Method B with 31 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 30 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJ1WbVjggwJM3uOTZ2dHx5c=
Result Method B with 30 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 29 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZDiI785bQRbNeZX2aNFQvZo=
Result Method B with 29 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 28 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZMmLT/ycIHWz0sjPsdfg/ys=
Result Method B with 28 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 27 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZJDekWQLgx9tTUE/59ldSqs=
Result Method B with 27 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 26 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZKIkr5xwCc8SS9eSnw715vk=
Result Method B with 26 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 25 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZFAtZM8oTV/uTBb6OccqErc=
Result Method B with 25 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 24 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZD5BAXR9qZav1rG5NnaLEQQ=
Result Method B with 24 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 23 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZFof3ATUQWJqiZ2wZ6Gj4Vc=
Result Method B with 23 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 22 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZNWhgIhTYyERb74rKEl8bos=
Result Method B with 22 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 21 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZIsgSoHGJT3XysDLqmV9Bi0=
Result Method B with 21 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 20 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZO0ZdC9DzISByS5T1Rx4hQ4=
Result Method B with 20 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 19 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZBFfUwWYJ5ECKF2JexKf8Xk=
Result Method B with 19 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 18 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZNkZyUqqwkELWI4JN14M2RE=
Result Method B with 18 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 17 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZOKdO3s345tAlCrN+q3QV68=
Result Method B with 17 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 16 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZE6HtWd1ZLwZMvy3E9Bm5CI=
Result Method B with 16 characters: /ppBS775B1KRShB+QKTLZA==
Result Method A with 15 characters: OMMFxti/svtQ/Z5fqaLaEg==
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Encrypted data is 0 for text "Under 15 charac" with length 15
   at IssueEncryptionStreamEmpty.Program.GetNonWorkingEncrypted(String text, ICryptoTransform encryptor) in /media/sasw/Data/src/issue-encryption-stream-empty/Program.cs:line 53
   at IssueEncryptionStreamEmpty.Program.Main(String[] args) in /media/sasw/Data/src/issue-encryption-stream-empty/Program.cs:line 17

Process finished with exit code 134.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `writer` is no longer scoped to `cryptoStream`'s using block, it is now disposed right before returning from your function (as opposed to being disposed when `cryptoStream`'s scope ends). But it didn't flush its contents to the stream, because you didn't call `Flush` on it, and its `AutoFlush` property defaults to `false`.

```cs
public object GetEncryptedOrDefault(object value, ICryptoTransform encryptor)
{
    if (encryptor is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encryptor));
    }
    var isEncryptionNeeded = value != null;
    if (isEncryptionNeeded)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        var valueAsText = value.ToString();
        writer.Write(valueAsText);
        writer.Flush();

        var encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        return encryptedText;
    }

    return default;
}
```

In your first example, the `writer` is disposed (thus flushing its buffer) before using up the stream it writes to, so the stream isn't empty when trying to access it.

**UPDATE:**
While looking through `CryptoStream.Dispose`'s source code, I've noticed a call to [`FlushFinalBlock`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/System/Security/Cryptography/CryptoStream.cs,648), which is the reason for the outputs being mismatched.

As for the input length problem, `encryptor.InputBlockSize` is equal to 16, which is why writing a text with 15 or less characters and not calling `FlushFinalBlock` (note that [`CryptoStream.Flush`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/System/Security/Cryptography/CryptoStream.cs,155) is a no-op) results in an empty stream.

So, the again-working code becomes:

```cs
private static string GetWorkingEncrypted(string text, ICryptoTransform encryptor)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
    writer.Write(text);
    writer.Flush();
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    var encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
    var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    return encryptedText;
}
```

Comment: When I read your answer it made sense. But surprisingly it does now work. memory stream remains empty despite of flushing the writer.

Comment: Using your code I was able to reproduce your issue, then after adding `writer.Flush()` the issue was gone. I'm afraid I can't help you unless you update your question.

Comment: Done. UPDATE 1 added with the real problem. Both ways produce different results despite the `writer.Flush()` and the issue seems to have more to do with the length of the text to encrypt. It's really odd. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Brilliant! thanks so much for your time. It still looks odd to me this mismatch, but I'm glad you found the reason!